# Вызов метода messages.removeChatUser - VK Android SDK

Tags: android, android-sdk, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, запрос

В VK API существует такой метод как messages.removeChatUser, позволяющий как исключить пользователя из беседы, так и покинуть беседу самому. Не могу разобраться, как сделать запрос к этому методу.
Я начинаю запрос таким образом:

```
VKRequest request = VKApi.messages().
```

но после точки есть лишь часть методов и нет removeChatUser. На скриншотах видно, что в **wall** их достаточно много, а в **messages** многие методы отсутствуют. Или я что-то делаю не так?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я также пытался сделать запрос к методу следующим образом:

```
VKRequest request = new VKRequest("messages.removeChatUser", VKParameters.from("chat_id", 2, "user_id", мой id));
```

Но, кажется, такой способ тоже не прошёл.
Помогите сделать запрос к vk.com/dev/messages/removeChatUser.

Answer (score 1):

Может быть "капитаню", но первым делом нужно проверить есть ли доступ "Для вызова этого метода Ваше приложение должно иметь права: messages". 
Часть методов не реализованы в VK SDK Andoid, поэтому для их вызова необходимо делать запросы.
Запрос у вас написан правильно. Пришлите код ошибки, который вам приходит